# org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object

Tags: android

I am writing an android application.Can someone plz let me know which object is unterminated here ??

```
12-24 17:47:26.642: DEBUG/youtubeviewer(273): 
12-24 17:47:26.672: WARN/youtubeviewer(273): org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 23 of [{ "id":"12,                               
12-24 17:47:26.672: WARN/youtubeviewer(273):        "name":"Pets & Animals"},
12-24 17:47:26.672: WARN/youtubeviewer(273): 
12-24 17:47:26.672: WARN/youtubeviewer(273): { "id":"13,
12-24 17:47:26.672: WARN/youtubeviewer(273):        "name":"Science & Technology"},
12-24 17:47:26.672: WARN/youtubeviewer(273): 
12-24 17:47:26.672: WARN/youtubeviewer(273): { "id":"14,
12-24 17:47:26.672: WARN/youtubeviewer(273):        "name":"Travel & Events"}
12-24 17:47:26.672: WARN/youtubeviewer(273): 
12-24 17:47:26.672: WARN/youtubeviewer(273): ]
```

My JSON object:

```
[{ "id":"12, "name":"Pets & Animals"}, { "id":"13, "name":"Science & Technology"}, { "id":"14, "name":"Travel & Events"} ]
```

Comment: here is my json object 

[{ "id":"12,
       "name":"Pets & Animals"},

{ "id":"13,
       "name":"Science & Technology"},

{ "id":"14,
       "name":"Travel & Events"}

]

Answer (score 2):

You are having `"id":"12` which should be `"id":"12"` and same is the case with other ids.

Comment: @PareshMayani : i am getting json response :
{"ValidateUserResult":"[{\"StatusCode\":2,\"StatusMessage\":\"Invalid UserName\/Password\"}]"}


can you please suggest me what I am doing wrong here?

but when I parsing it, it giving me  

org.json.JSONException: Value [{"StatusCode":2,"StatusMessage":"Invalid UserName/Password"}] at ValidateUserResult of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: @Shubh yes there is error actually. Proposed Response format is like: {
    "ValidateUserResult": {
        "StatusCode": 2,
        "StatusMessage": "Invalid UserName/Password"
    }
}

Comment: @PareshMayani : thanks there is an syntax error in string :

{"ValidateUserResult":"[{"StatusCode":2,"StatusMessage":"Invalid UserName\/Password"}]"}
 
replce "[ with [ and "] with ]..work  for me.

Comment: @PareshMayani: do u have idea about it
i want to check for any json object perticular value exist or not ? like here {"ValidateUserResult":[{"Sys_User_ID":69,"my_id":23}]} i want to check in response "my_id" string is available or not?

Comment: @Shubh Best practice is to send "" (empty string) from server.